# DOM parser doesn't see subnodes

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom, xml-parsing

I trying to parse Lingvo xml dictionary with help of DOM parser.

***Problem:*** DOM parser doesn't see the subnodes of `card` node (see code below).

***Question?:*** How to pull `word` and `translation` nodes from `card` node

***My code:***

```
import entity.Item;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DOMParser {

    public void parseXMLFile(String xmlFilePath) throws IOException, SAXException {
        Document document = builder.parse(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(xmlFilePath));
        List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
        NodeList nodeList = document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
        //iterates through cards
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            System.out.println(node.getNodeName());
            if (node instanceof Element) {
                if ("card".equals(node.getNodeName())) {
                    // HERE node hasn't got anything!!! I mean attributes, childs etc.
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***My xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<dictionary formatVersion="5" title="User ;vocabulary_user1" sourceLanguageId="1058" destinationLanguageId="1033" nextWordId="611" targetNamespace="http://www.abbyy.com/TutorDictionary">
    <statistics readyMeaningsQuantity="90" activeMeaningsQuantity="148" learnedMeaningsQuantity="374" />
    <card>
        <word>загальна цікавість</word>
        <meanings>
            <meaning>
                <statistics status="4" answered="122914" />
                <translations>
                    <word>genaral wondering</word>
                </translations>
            </meaning>
        </meanings>
    </card>
</dictionary>
```

Comment: check this for basics of parsing xml http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/.... how to access the node and its value

Comment: @Naren I've already read this tutoril http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive approach to read through all your contents without getting into the mess of nested `for` loops.

For your xml:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException,
            SAXException, IOException {
        InputStream path = new FileInputStream("dom.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(path);
        traverse(document.getDocumentElement());

    }

    public static void traverse(Node node) {
        NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
            Node currentNode = list.item(i);
            traverse(currentNode);

        }

        if (node.getNodeName().equals("word")) {
            System.out.println("This -> " + node.getTextContent());
        }

    }
```

Gives,

```
This -> загальна цікавість
This -> genaral wondering
```