# DOM xml parsing difficulties in java

Tags: java, xml-parsing

```
<XML>
<log>
  <date>20022014</date>
  <time>2323</time>
  <schools>
    <school name="ahss"/>
    <student>shiva</student>
    <class>B</class>
  </schools>
</log>
<log>...</log>
</XML>
```

need to parse this xml format using DOM i have tried many substitutes but i couldn't get it
is there any one to give shoulder

Comment: A little more detail would be useful - as in what you have already done and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21703474/dom-parser-doesnt-see-subnodes/21703679#21703679

Comment: You are missing a closing </XML> tag

Comment: you have not closed your </school> tag.

Comment: Your xml is incomplete as suggested. what other problem you are facing?

Comment: Just want to get those values inside the xml tags, there will be multiple school tags inside schools